# How to add an image to a view

Tags: android

So i Currently have this:

```
final class Question {

private final String questionType;
private final String question;
private final ArrayList<String> answers;

private Question(final String questionType, final String question, final ArrayList<String> answers) {
    this.questionType = questionType;
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
}

/**
 * Takes a comma separated String of the question type, the question, and the answers, and returns a {@link Question} representation of them.
 * 
 * @param input The input String made up of the type of question, the question itself, and the answers (comma separated).
 * @return a {@link Question} representation of the input string.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 */
public static Question parse(final String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    final String[] questionComponents;
    final String questionType;
    final String question;
    final ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Which Feeds off this:

Entertainment,Adrien Brody won a Best Actor Oscar for which movie?,The        Pianist,The Village,King Kong,Dummy
Entertainment,Alec Guinness won a Best Actor Oscar for which movie?,The Bridge on the River Kwai,The Fall of the Roman Empire,The Horse's Mouth,The Lavender Hill Mob
Entertainment,Sir Alec Guinness won a Best Actor Oscar for which movie?,The Bridge on the River Kwai,A Run for Your Money,Last Holiday,Raise the Titanic
Entertainment,Art Carney won a Best Actor Oscar for which movie?,Harry and Tonto,Roadie,The Late Show,Lanigan's Rabbi
Entertainment,Broderick Crawford won a Best Actor Oscar for which movie?,All the King's Men,Black Angel,Born Yesterday,The Time of Your Life

Im Just not sure how to add an image to a text list would i just have an extra row with @drawable/image  and how would i impliment that into the class?

Answer (score 0):

If You are using image *URL* then put `String` or if you are using images in **drawable** the use **`int (R.drawable.image)`**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the image needs its own variable, there is no way to add an image to an array of strings. You can pass the image id you wish to use using `R.drawable.image_id` via your parse method.

Comment: so then what would i call the images? like say there was 20? would i nott just put in the text file @drawable/image1 and make that become the image source of the imageview?